Unable to open an Existing React Application
I have a react application that I am trying to make some changes on. I am unable to open and run the application. I have installed node and yarn
Node version: Node.js v20.11.0.
Yarn version: yarn install v1.22.22
Java Version: java version "22.0.2" 2024-07-16
The errors I am getting are when I run yarn android. I am getting this error
` FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details`

and
Class 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

1.Update Kotlin Version:
If possible, update your project to use Kotlin 1.9.0. You can do this by modifying your build.gradle file (or build.gradle.kts if using Kotlin DSL). Find the Kotlin version setting, which typically looks like this:
android/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.1'
}

Change it to:
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.0'
}

2.Clean and Rebuild:
./gradlew clean build

Following these steps should help you resolve the version mismatch and get your project compiling successfully again. Let me know if you need further assistance!
